# The client and server cannot communicate, because they do not possess a common algorithm

Tags: sites-9, microservices, https

We Enabled SSL Certificate for all our micro services. We Noticed that its working on our development environment, But it not working on the UAT. We are able to access the https service URL successfully from the browser but when we try to enable the same from the topology we are getting following Error.

Can anyone suggest if they have seen similar error. Please share the details

Answer (score 2, accepted):

refer this [link](http://hem-kant.blogspot.com/2018/07/sdl-web-and-tls-12-or-higher.html)

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft.NETFramework\v4.0.30319]”SchUseStrongCrypto”=dword:00000001

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft.NETFramework\v4.0.30319]”SchUseStrongCrypto”=dword:00000001

Hope it helps!